# how to ignore @Where hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity Author

```
@Data
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@Where(clause = "isDeleted=false")
public class Author
```

and an entity Book

```
@Data
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
public class Book {
...

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,orphanRemoval = true)
        @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", nullable = false )
        private Author author;
    }
```

And i need to get all books even if author is deleted. I use JpaRepository:

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {}
```

But when i try it

```
bookRepository.findAll()
```

i get an exception: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find Author with id 1

Tried this but it didn't help me:

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {

    @Override
    @Query(value = "from Book as b where b.author.isDeleted = true")
    List<Book> findAll();
```

How can i avoid @where?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't, once `@Where`-ed, always `@Where`-ed :/ Unless you go via native queries, in which case Hibernate doesn't append that clause IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GeneralAuthor 

@Entity
@DynamicInsert
public class Author extends GeneralAuthor {}

@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@Where(clause = "isDeleted=false")
public class ActiveAuthor extends GeneralAuthor {}
```

Here `GeneralAuthor` is a base data structure (copy paste it from your current `Author`).

`Author` renamed to `ActiveAuthor`, providing more information on what it is: an active (not deleted) author record.

And a new entity `Author` entity allows you to access any kind of authors (deleted or not deleted), and should be used within mapping to the `Book`.

This will allow you to reuse all your data structure, and have flexible views on the same Author  entity. And note: `Author` and `ActiveAuthor` do not declare any own field.